# How this function f1() will execute?

Tags: c, operators

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f1(char* str, int index)
{
   *(str + index) &= ~32;
}
int main()
{
   char arr[] = "gatecsit";
   f1(arr, 0);
   printf("%s", arr);
   return 0;
}
```

How is function **f1()** working?
Being specific ***(str + index) &= ~32;** this one....
thanks

Comment: You have not accepted any of the answers. So there must still be something unsolved to you. However, it is unclear what exactly you are asking. Surely at least one of the five operators is already known to you? Is it only the combination of them? Do you have a problem with the operator precedence? Is anything about declaration or use of the parameters unclear? Also, you surely have run the code an seen the output. Is anything unclear about that? Can you state more specifically what your problem is by referring to the output?

Comment: It computes the value of a character based on the value of a character so everything depends on the character encoding being used. The literal string uses the execution character set that you tell the compiler to use. `printf` effectively uses the character encoding that the user's terminal is set to. Hopefully, they are compatible. Standard library functions use the character encoding associated with the program's current locale. Most C runtimes initialize the locale to terminal's, making standard library functions and your programs work how the user probably expects. Try "ÿ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
*(str + index)
```

is equivalent to

```
str[index]
```

So the character at position `index` is changed the following way

```
*(str + index) &= ~32;
```

In the ASCII table lower case letters differ from upper case letters by having one more set bit. For example the lower case letter `'a'` has the code in hex `61` while the upper case letter `'A"` has the code in hex `41`. So the difference is equal to the value in hex `20` that in decimal is equal to `32`.

So the original expression resets the corresponding bit in the character to 0 converting a lower case letter to the upper case letter.

Answer (score 1):

I think f1() capitalizes the first letter of the string by exploiting a property of ASCII that means that corresponding lower and upper-case letters differ by 32. For example the code for 'A' is 65, while that for 'a' is 97. The '&= ~32' bit of the code will turn of bit-5 of the ASCII representation of the character str[index], which should turn the 'g' into 'G'. This should be fine for strings that contain only ordinary letters, but will have strange effects on digits and punctuation characters.

Answer (score 1):

The code removes 1 bit from the character 
 effectively subtracting 32 from the byte or 0x20.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void f1(char* str, int index)
{
 // The code removes 1 bit from the character at the position `str[index]`
 // effectively subtracting 32 from that character
 // Capital letters in ASCII are apart by 32 (0x20) from small letters 

 // Since 'a' = 0x61 and 'A' = 0x41  'a' - 32 = 'A'
 // Since 'b' = 0x62 and 'B' = 0x42  'b' - 32 = 'B'

 // `~` is a binary negation operator 0 -> 1;  1 -> 0
 // `&` is a binary AND
 // x &= y; is equivalent to x = x & y;

 // ~0x20 = 0b11011111    

   *(str + index) &= ~0x20; // 0x20 = 32;
}


int main()
{
   int i;
   char arr[] = "gatecsit";
   size_t len = strlen(arr);


  for(i = 0; i< len; i++)
      printf(" %c " , arr[i]);   

   printf("\n");

  for(i = 0; i< len; i++)
      printf(" %X" , arr[i]);

   printf("\n");

  // convert all letters:  
   for(i = 0; i< len; i++)
      f1(arr, i);

   printf("\n");

  for(i = 0; i< len; i++)
      printf(" %c " , arr[i]);  

   printf("\n");

  for(i = 0; i< len; i++)
      printf(" %X" , arr[i]);

   return 0;
 }
```

Output:
The small and capital are letters apart by 0x20 (or 32 decimal).
This can be clearly seen from this printout:

```
 g  a  t  e  c  s  i  t 
 67 61 74 65 63 73 69 74

 G  A  T  E  C  S  I  T 
 47 41 54 45 43 53 49 54
```